# Change Site Logo or Menu Logo Per Page

Tags: customization, pages, logo

**Background:** 
Conference company with multiple events, on each event page would like to switch out the brand's logo with the event logo along with custom menu for event.

Using standard WP install for brand's 3 events. Then a page per each year's event details.

**Issue:**
How can I create a custom menu that changes the logo per specified page? 
Recommended plugin? 
Logo-less site with custom code in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a workaround.

I used UberMenu the Wordpress plugin to insert images into menus which I then set on a per page basis.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...
Maybe Multiuser Install - a different blog for each company...

Or if you'd rather not have a blog network...

Create a  "Company" taxonomy, which uses the taxonomy-meta class for uploading a company logo, and menu name. That way you can create a menu for each company, and link to it in the "menu name" taxonomy meta for each company you add to the company taxonomy.

Comment: Not very familiar with taxonomies. Any specific material you can point me to?